# MySQL Query with Group by for Stated Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that returns a single row after group by query. For example I have a table **tblTest** with columns:

```
Id, Name,   Type,  Amount
1, Receipt, Cash   100
2, Receipt, Card   200
3, Receipt, Cheque 250
4, Receipt, Card   150
5, Receipt, Cash   100
6, Payment, Cash   300
7, Payment, Cheque 400
```

After Group By Query

```
Select Name,Type,Amount from tblTest where 1=1 Group by Type
```

it returns me,

```
1 Receipt  Cash   200
2 Receipt  Card   350
3 Receipt  Cheque 250
4 Payment, Cash   300
5 Payment, Cheque 400
```

but what I need to return is something like

```
Name    Cash Card Cheque
Receipt 200  350  250
Payment 300  NULL 400
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a basic pivot query along with a summation:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Cash'   THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) Cash,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Card'   THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) Card,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Cheque' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) Cheque
FROM tblTest
GROUP BY
    Name;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tim Biegeleisen, one more correction if Type Cash,Card,Cheque in above data are not predifind, that may come dynamically then how could i manage it..?

Comment: @Vijay You would need to write some dynamic SQL to handle this.

Comment: can you help me to build Dynamic Query..?

Comment: You should ask a new question if you really need this. Changing your requirements now will invalidate this entire question.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen  please find my new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373922/mysql-select-query-to-generate-dynamic-column-result