# MySQL Select Query to generate dynamic column Result

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, aggregate-functions, case-when

I need to write a query that returns a Column Dynamically. For example I have a table tblTest with columns:

```
Id, Name,   Type,  Amount
1, Receipt, Cash   100
2, Receipt, Card   200
3, Receipt, Cheque 250
4, Receipt, Card   150
5, Receipt, Cash   100
6, Payment, Cash   300
7, Payment, Cheque 400
```

SQL Query :

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Cash'   THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) Cash,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Card'   THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) Card,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Cheque' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) Cheque
FROM tblTest
GROUP BY
    Name;
```

it returns me,

[image]

above result is as per my requirement but in my case Type Cash,Card,Cheque,etc in above data are not predefined, that may come dynamically then how could i manage it,Please help me to build dynamic columns SQL for that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? Do you mean that when the DB changes, the SUM is re-calculated and you html is re-written?

Comment: @Yuri in above stated table column Type value Cash,Card,Cheque is not predefined it may increase with Paytm,wallet etc...

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. It's much simpler.

Comment: [_Dynamic builder_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Comment: You can create query string using for loop and execute later.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use *Dynamic pivot*

Create your *pivot* query Dynamically.

The main steps are as follows

1. Declare a variable `@sql` to carry your `SUM` function and `CASW WHEN` Expression
2. use `CONCAT` to combine your `SUM` function and `CASW WHEN` Expression string and main `select` string.
3. use `EXECUTE` function execute SQL Dynamically.

look like this.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN Type =''',
      Type,
      ''' THEN Amount END) AS ',
      Type
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tblTest;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
                    Name,', @sql, ' 
                   FROM tblTest
                   GROUP BY
                    Name;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Result**

```
    Name    Cash    Card    Cheque
1   Payment 300     NULL    400
2   Receipt 200      350    250
```

[SQLfiddle](http://rextester.com/YJNKZ12348)

Answer (score -1):

Hej,

Hope i got you right.

```
select name, type, sum(CASE WHEN Type in (select DISTINCT sub.type from 
tblTest sub) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as "sum" from tblTest
group by name, type;
```