# Group by date and sum of all unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I'm trying to write a SQL query for this report to group by date and also get the count of all unique values. The problem I have is that I do not know how many unique values I will have ahead of time.

Sample Table:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Date  |  Name  |
+--------+--------+
| 1/1/18 | John   |
| 1/1/18 | John   |
| 1/1/18 | Sylvia |
| 1/2/18 | Sylvia |
+--------+--------+
```

This is what I tried but it requires me to know that John and Sylvia exist in the table. What is the workaround if there were 50,000 unique names without having to type out all the CASE statement.

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name='John' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS John,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name='Sylvia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sylvia
FROM myTable
  GROUP BY date;
```

Expected output:

```
+--------+------+--------+-----+
|  Date  | John | Sylvia | ... |
+--------+------+--------+-----+
| 1/1/18 |    2 |      1 | ... |
| 1/2/18 |    0 |      1 | ... |
+--------+------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: My first approach would be to group by date and name and get the count of each row. This doesn't pivot the names to columns but it gives you an easy filterable set of data

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
SELECT date, name, count(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY date, name;
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Dynamic PIVOT.`

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

  set @sql = 'select * 
             from  (select *,count(name)cnt from #mytable group by name,date)A
             PIVOT
             ( sum(cnt)
               FOR name
               in ( '+stuff(( select distinct ', '+ name from #mytable group by name for xml path('')),1,1,'')+')
             )as PIVOTTABLE'

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

This link may help you [MySQL Select Query to generate dynamic column Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373922/mysql-select-query-to-generate-dynamic-column-result)